# Noun for a large puddle

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns

Puddle, as a noun, refers to a small pool of water, usually small enough to walk through but not large enough for a raft.

What would a (temporary) pool of water larger than a puddle be called?

> It just rained, so watch out for puddles

vs

> It just rained quite a bit and there's a [large puddle] on the corner, so take the other road

I would imagine a *pool* of water might be correct, but I've never heard anyone refer to a body of standing rain water as a pool. And *floodwater* would be too much.

Comment: We usually go with hyperbole and say, “There’s now a lake on the corner so you’ll have to take the long way around.”

Comment: Otherwise you just say, “The road is flooded.”. You might also say that there is *standing water on the road*.

Comment: ***Pond*** can be used as a verb to mean "(especially of water) to collect into a pond or large puddle" (www.dictionary.com/browse/pond). Notice that this definition explicitly mentions large puddles. This suggests that some people might use "pond" to mean larger puddle.

Comment: A small pond is called a *pondlet*. I like your idea of *pool*. It suggests something bigger than a puddle.

Comment: A large puddle is a *large puddle*. A pool of water of any size is a ***pool of water***. In particular, a *pool of water* is likely to be considered, without further context, to be a large puddle or something larger.

Comment: Pool captures what you're looking for perfectly.

Comment: I think the expected size of a "pool" depends on context. "The sink overflowed and now there's a pool of water on the floor" suggests a small amount of water, much tinier than a puddle.

Comment: @Barmar fair enough. I've just never heard anyone describe a large puddle as a pool - not that it's not correct. Maybe (USA) we don't have a different word for it.

Comment: @Raystafarian I haven't heard that use much, either. I like Jim's suggestion to call it a lake, I've done that myself.

Comment: I've certainly heard (in the US) a puddle described as a "pool", but it's only so-so common.  And the term does not really suggest something larger than a medium-to-large puddle.  I would agree with Jim that if "huge puddle" doesn't hack it then "lake" would often be used, or "river", if the water is flowing.  There is no real pecking order of terms.

Comment: And of course one must repeat the old joke:  Frank:  "It's raining cats and dogs out there."  Joe:  "I know.  I  just stepped in a poodle."

Comment: Dr Foster *stepped in a puddle **up to his middle***, so evidently puddles can get pretty deep/big (at least in Gloucester).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've identified the best answer in your question: *pool*.

M-W:

> [*pool*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pool): a small
>   body of **standing** liquid [emphasis added]

Your example:

> It just rained quite a bit and there's a (large) *pool* on the corner,
>   so take the other road.

I've often heard people refer to "a large body of **standing** rainwater" as a *pool*. [emphasis added]

Answer (score 0):

A (temporary) ***swamp*** comes very close to what you seek.

> It just rained quite a bit and there's a (temporary) ***swamp*** on
>   the corner, so take the other road.

ODO:

> **[swamp](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/swamp)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1.1** An area of waterlogged ground:
>   ‘the ceaseless deluge had turned the lawn into a swamp’
>
> ‘In the Serra da Bocaina, plants grow along the edges of montane
>   forests, as well as in well drained high-altitude grasslands and
>   temporary swamps that arc flooded in the summer months.’

Comment: I myself wouldn't use *swamp* for a flooded area,   but it's there in the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, @AlanCarmack! It was quite disheartening to see downvotes for something straight out of a reputed dictionary; so, your support helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't really fit in the "road" scenario.

Comment: +1 If a lot of debris is in the puddle or pool, it could be quite like a swamp.  And if the road is a dirt road, swamp could be just right.